# How to install Transmission using Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, transmission, transmission-daemon

I am completely new in Docker. I want to install [Transmission](https://transmissionbt.com) using Docker  (i.e. I don't want to use [linuxserver.io/transmission](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/transmission))

For the moment my `Dockerfile` is :

```
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install transmission-daemon -y
EXPOSE 9091 51413/tcp 51413/udp
```

But how to give the settings.json file? How to run my Dockerfile? Do I need a `docker-compose.yml` file?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: This question is a bit broad right now: there are lots of resources out there that walk through the process of containerizing an application.

Comment: I did not find any ressource installing from scratch. (Yes there is but it always uses the unofficial method of https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/transmission which I don't want to use!)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how come you don't want to use the LinuxServer container? Their containers are top notch, I use a ton of them. If it's because you want to use your own `settings.json` file with it you can just mount it on container startup so those settings are used.

Comment: @J.ScottElblein Don't know, I thought it was yet another stupid developer with great influence that I have to trust XD and, most important, I am really interested to learn how to do it myself :)

Comment: Ahh ok, for learning i can see it. As far as their quality though no worries, they're Grade A. In fact whenever i go looking for a container i haven't used yet I always look to see if LinuxServer has it first (and I'm usually disappointed when there isn't one, lol).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First create a `Dockerfile` file :

```
FROM alpine:3

RUN apk --no-cache add transmission-daemon \
    && mkdir -p /transmission/config \
    && chmod -R 1777 /transmission \
    && rm -rf /tmp/*


STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/transmission-daemon", "--foreground", "--config-dir", "/transmission/config"]
```

And a `docker-compose.yml` file :

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  transmission:
    image: transmission
    container_name: transmission-container

    ports:
      - "9091:9091/tcp"
      - "51413:51413/tcp"
      - "51413:51413/udp"
    tmpfs:
      - /tmp
    volumes:
      - /Users/jean/mystuff/config:/transmission/config
      - /Users/jean/mystuff/downloads:/transmission/downloads
      - /Users/jean/mystuff/incomplete:/transmission/incomplete
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Don't forget to put your `settings.json` file in the config folder (Users/jean/mystuff/config/settings.json). And stay consistent in this json file! Use `/transmission/downloads` for `download-dir` property and so on...

Then we have to build the image (open Terminal and go where the `Dockerfile` is located)

```
docker build -t transmission .
```

And finally start up, by doing (open Terminal and go where the `docker-compose.yml` is located)

```
docker-compose up -d
```

<sub>Many thanks to : https://gitlab.com/alexhaydock/docker-transmission</sub>